# How to add Git Project in android studio

Tags: android, git

I want to add the following into my android Studio project , please tell me how to do that.

https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-sdk

Answer (score 3):

Option 1.-Clone It First With Git Clone https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-sdk then Import it in Android Studio

Option 2- [Download this Repo](https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-sdk/archive/master.zip) From Here As a Zip File, Open It and Extract, Then Import in Android Studio.

Option 3- Open Android Studio DashBoard And Click on Checkout From Version Control, And Parte your Repo Link there, It Will DOwnload And Open It ASAP.

If you want to Use this Project as a module or library then Import It from File->New->Import Module->//.....// OR add this as your Dependencies ---

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.dhis2:dhis2-android-sdk:8722ca9586'
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Actually i do not want to import it , i want to use it in my another project. Suppose i have created a simple helloworld app in android studio now i want to use this Git project into my helloworld app, then how can i do it

Comment: Answer Updated You You want to use it As a Library

Comment: yes thanks ..but i got this following error when i was trying to import it as a module: Module name: app.............project already contains this module name

Comment: That's why your main project name module is called "app", you must provide another name for the imported module

Comment: when i give another name then following error comes:                        Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'My Application' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: Now i am getting this error: Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.

Comment: Then Specify it to the leatest and Make Sure Both Project using the Same Version of Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip from github page, unzip it and then go to Android Studio > File > New -> Import Project -> Select your project and import it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually i do not want to import it , i want to use it in my another project. Suppose i have created a simple helloworld app in android studio now i want to use this Git project into my helloworld app, then how can i do it

Comment: Look at this tutorial http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/library-project-module-as-dependency-in-android-studio

Comment: I follow all the steps and now i am getting this error:                       Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' not found.

Comment: Now i am getting this error: Error:Cause: buildToolsVersion is not specified.